# How to post from array mutiple request with axios in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

i try to post with axios from an array to an api php file and get the responses one by one not just one request. I read something about axios.all() but can't figure it out i am new to javascript.

```
<div id="app">
    <center>
<div id="area">
   <textarea v-model="sent" name="sent" id="sent" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control">
   </textarea>
    <br>
    <button v-on:click="insert" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</div>

<div id="good" v-for="message of messages">
    <span><h2>Good</h2></span>

        {{ message }}

</div>

</center>
</div>
```

And here is the vuejs code.

```
<script>
     new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 data:{
     sent:[],
     messages:[]
 },
         methods:{
           insert:function (){
               const vm = this;
               splitz.forEach(function(entry){
               axios.post('/one.php', {
                   sent: vm.entry
               }).then(response => {
                   vm.messages.push(response.data.onefinal) ;
                       console.log(response.data);
                   }
               ).catch(function(error){ console.log(error); });
               }
            }
         },
         computed:{
             splitz: function () {
                 return this.sent.split('\n')
             }
         }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
// Create an array of post requests from splitz array
var requests = splitz.map(entry => axios.post('/one.php', { sent: this.entry }))

// Send all requests using axios.all
axios.all(requests)
.then(results => results.map(response => response.data.onefinal))
.then(newMessages => {
    console.log('New Messages:', newMessages)
    this.messages.push.apply(this.messages, newMessages)
})
```

**Edit:** to send the requests one by one:

```
insert: function() {

    var vm = this;

    function sendRequest(arr, i) {
        var entry = arr[i];
        axios.post('/one.php', { sent: entry }).then(function (response) {
            vm.messages.push(response.data.onefinal);
            if (i < arr.length - 1) {
                sendRequest(arr, ++i);
            }
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    sendRequest(this.splitz, 0);

}
```

Comment: does it go one by one like sending a request then get response and so on for each string in the array ? or just send the entire array on time.

Comment: This will send all the requests at the same time and gather all the responses in an array. If you want to send them one by one, just let me know and i'll edit the answer.

Comment: yes one by one like send request get response send request get response can you help ? thanks

Comment: thanks sorry to ask where do i put it in the insert method ?

Comment: yes, you can replace the content of insert method with it.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I understand but which line?

Comment: this line 83 i think i do something wrong can you put the hole code like edit mine with yours thanks

Comment: Ok, I removed all of the ES6 syntax, try again.

Comment: i dont have errors on load but when i submit the form i get (index):88 Uncaught ReferenceError: splitz is not defined

Comment: i have it on computed mayby i need a var ?

Comment: No problem, just use `this.splitz` instead.

Comment: now i have TypeError: vm.sendRequest is not a function
    at (index):80 sorry if i busy you

Comment: awesome! glad i was able to help :)